# How C language macro recognizes variables and appends them to other locations?

Tags: c

I want to implement functions similar to the following.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define JSON_X(...) #__VA_ARGS__

#define JSON_M(args, ...) JSON_X(__VA_ARGS__), args

#define JSON_S(...) JSON_M(number, __VA_ARGS__)

#define JSON_INT(x) %d

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    
    int number = 12;

    printf (
        JSON_S(
            <N>{
                "Class": "105",
                /* Flag is a number */
                "Flag": JSON_INT(number),
                "Value": 666
            }</N>
        )
    );

    return 0;
}
```

In other words, implement a clear definition of static Json packages in C language.

For example, If I type in macros

```c
JSON_S (
    <N>{
        "Class": "105",
        /* Flag is a number */
        "Flag": JSON_INT(number),
        "Value": 666
    }</N>
)
```

I hope macro output

```c
"<N>{ \"Class\": \"105\", \"Flag\": %d, \"Value\": 666 }</N>", number
```

Then I can put it in `printf`

```c
printf("<N>{ \"Class\": \"105\", \"Flag\": %d, \"Value\": 666 }</N>", number);
```

In the macro JSON_S, the `number` variable is recognized and appended to the end.

The problem now is that I can't recognize that the number variable is defined and automatically appended to the end of the parameter in the macro JSON_S.

Comment: What are you hoping to get as the output from this?  What do you actually get?

Comment: There are too many questions. `How C language macro recognizes variables` Macros do not recognize variables. `How C language recognizes variables and appends them to other locations ?` I do not understand the question, C compiler recognizes variables. `Is there an ingenious way to achieve the above functions?` Is too broad. You have to program it.

Comment: The macto does expand to what you "hope" it will -- so what is your question?  The `number` that is the argument to `JSON_INT` is ignored (per the definition) and the `number` in `JSON_S`'s body is hardcoded, so this won't work for anything not called `number`.

Comment: Please be aware that the preprocessor and the compiler are separated beasts. Both have their specific tasks and work very much independently. Just as a hint to help yourself: Look at the resulting C source _after_ preprocessing. Serious C compilers provide an option to produce that result, for GCC it is `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think that you are pehaps asking is how to get the argument from the JSON_INT macro into the JSON_S macro.  There's not really any way to that, but you could do something like:

```
#define JSON_X(...) #__VA_ARGS__

#define JSON_S(JSON, ...) JSON_X JSON, __VA_ARGS__

#define JSON_INT %d
    
    int number = 12;

    printf (
        JSON_S((
            <N>{
                "Class": "105",
                /* Flag is a number */
                "Flag": JSON_INT,
                "Value": 666
            }</N>
        ), number)
    );
```

which will expand to the printf you want, but its really no better than just writing the printf directly with no macros.  Perhaps with a "raw" string literal if you're using a C compiler that supports that (common when the compiler also supports C++, as it is a standard C++ feature).